# Why is the derivative at an instantaneous point, but the integral is the area of the whole function?

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing Calc theory for an upcoming course and I can't really piece this part together.

So, the derivative of a function is another function that can tell you the **instantaneous** slope of two related variables.

But the integral of the same function is another function that will tell you the **total** area under the graph, or the sum of all instantaneous multiplicative relations of the two variables.

So the derivative can tell you how a specific set of variables are related, their slope, at that point in the function but it won't tell you how the slope of the function behaves before that point. Whereas the integral will tell you another relationship between the variables, the area, but it does it for the whole function, sort of like a summary of the function.

It seems like a discrepancy. Like either the result of the derivative at a certain point should be a summary of the instantaneous slope and the previous slopes, like the integral. Or the the integral should be just the area at that point like the derivative.

Maybe I'm overthinking it or getting to caught up in the graph representation of the relationship. But if anybody could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a pure math question and thus off topic here. If other people agree, we can migrate it to [math.SE].

Comment: I agree that this should be migrated to mathematics, but for the sake of saving you some time, integrals and derivatives are not quite so simply intertwined as you think. There's far more advanced maths behind the link between the two. I suggest you look up Riemann Sums (Upper Riemann Sum and Lower Riemann Sum), and follow with Riemann integrals. In general, you are perhaps "getting too caught up in the graph representation of the relationship". But for a more complete understanding of that, yeah. MathSE!

Comment: Ok, I will ask there. Thanks.

Comment: The derivative and integral are just two different objects.  The derivative happens to give you local information about the function while the integral gives you global info.  I don't see why you should expect the same type of info from each.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think it should be a discrepancy?

Why should the derivative give you general information about all points? The definition of the derivative is local, it cannot give global information.

Same way, why should the integral be something local? The definition of the integral as a limit of Riemann sums is a global definition over the interval.

What confuses you is probably the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. 
But whenever when you use the FTC, when you derivate the function, **you derivate it at every point**. While the derivative at a point tells you what happens locally, the derivative of a function changes the function **everywhere**.
This makes the FTC, in some vague sense, a relation between two global operations.

Comment: +1, but as the OP is clearly something of a novice, I think elaborating the local/global distinction could help; these words are not usually mentioned in first courses, though they should be.